# Firestore Rules: What if a give document doesn't exist but is used in a get?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Consider this code:

```
match /shocking_contents_main_app/{shocking_content_main_app} {  // Do not specify any read/update/delete rules - OK, last check 2019/06/03
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.can_report_shocking_content == true 
                            && 
                exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.resource.data.reported_account_id))
                && 
                request.resource.data.reported_login == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.resource.data.reported_account_id)).data.login;
}
```

These rules are setup in the context of reporting some shocking content.

The last line checks whether the reported login equals the login of the reported user's ID. The "problem" is the following: the document `$(request.resource.data.reported_account_id)` under the path `/databases/$(database)/documents/users/` could not exist. If it doesn't exist, would Firestore Security Rules deny the query (expected behavior)? In other words: must I use `exists(...)`?

Another example is available in the first line: I check if the logged in user can report the content of someone else (`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.can_report_shocking_content == true`). But I don't use `exists(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a `get()` call fails, the entire check becomes false. It's important to realize that even if only one clause of a `allow` condition fails, the entire condition will fail.

So this rule will return `true`:

```
allow read: if true || false;
```

But this next rule will fail:

```
allow read: if true || get(document_that_does_not_exist);
```

If you possibly want a positive outcome when the document doesn't exist, you indeed will need to check whether it exists by using `exists()` first.

So this would return `true` again:

```
allow read: if true || exists(document_that_does_not_exist);
```

Comment: Sorry Frank, just:  could you confirm that a `null reference error` (in case `exists` isn't called and the document, or other, doesn't exist) will have the sole consequence to deny the query (as you explained)? just to be 100% clear, please

Comment: Calling `get()` on a non-existing reference will make the entire security check fail.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @FrankvanPuffelen. I tried to find complete documentation for security rules, but couldn't. I'd be very thankful if you share a link to complete api and documentation of firestore security rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - one clarification: wouldn't there be short-circuiting logic with `true || get(document_that_does_not_exist);`?  I thought firebase would not even attempt to look up the document from `get(document_that_does_not_exist)` due to short-circuiting boolean logic for rules.  Not sure if that is perhaps new since this answer.  See reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language.